# Dearness Allowance Calculator - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program that would Calculate the DA for my dad. I'm trying to get the whole function to be ran but it is not doing what I wanted it to do. Here below is the code that I wrote. Kindly correct the Errors in the program or any article that are related to this. I think I nested number of functions in `calculation()`

```
print('\t    DA CALCULATOR')


print('Enter the Appropriate answers and values')
linker1 = 4.63 * 4.93
linker2 = 2.88 * 4.63 * 4.93

#def base1960(m1,m2,m3,pm1,pm2,pm3,linker1):
#   m1 = 
#   sumOf3months = m1 + m2 + m3
#   print(f'The Sum of the DA Points is {sumOf3months} '

def calculation():
    m1 = float(input('Enter AICPIN for the 1st month : '))
    m2 = float(input('Enter AICPIN for the 2nd month : '))
    m3 = float(input('Enter AICPIN for the 3rd month : '))
    linker1 = 4.63 * 4.93
    linker2 = 2.88 * 4.63 * 4.93
    inpt = input('Do you want the linker value "2.88" to be computed which belongs to AICPIN BASE 2016 = 100.\n[y]es or [n]o   :')
    
    def lnkr1(m1,m2,m3,linker2,inpt):
        if inpt == 'y':
            m1 = m1 * linker2
            m2 = m2 * linker2
            m3 = m3 * linker2
            sum_of_m = m1+m2+m3
            avg_m = (sum_of_m)/3
            print(f'The DA Point for the present 3 months is {avg_m}')
        else:
            pass
    
    def lnkr2(m1,m2,m3,linker2,inpt):
        if inpt == 'y':
            m1 = m1 * linker1
            m2 = m2 * linker1
            m3 = m3 * linker1
            sum_of_m = m1+m2+m3
            avg_m = (sum_of_m)/3
            print(f'The DA Point for the present 3 months is {avg_m}')
        else:
            pass
    def preM():
        pM = input('Sir/Madam Do you have the DA Point of the Earlier 3 months or Do you have to compute it ? \n[y]es or [n]o .')
        if pM == 'y':
            bs1 = input('Do you want to include the linker 2.88 ? .[y] or [n] :: ')
            if bs1 == 'y':
                lnkr1()
            else:
                lnkr2()
            
while True: 
    try:
        calculation()

    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid Character')
```

And the first time when I wrote the code and ran it it threw me some errors. Please see the following code and there is not a lot of change in the code
***Variables*** are made ***local*** I think so. And the code and the error is given below

**Code:**

```
print('\t    DA CALCULATOR')


print('Enter the Appropriate answers and values')
linker1 = 4.63 * 4.93
linker2 = 2.88 * 4.63 * 4.93

#def base1960(m1,m2,m3,pm1,pm2,pm3,linker1):
#   m1 = 
#   sumOf3months = m1 + m2 + m3
#   print(f'The Sum of the DA Points is {sumOf3months} '

def calculation():
    global m1 = float(input('Enter AICPIN for the 1st month : '))
    global m2 = float(input('Enter AICPIN for the 2nd month : '))
    global m3 = float(input('Enter AICPIN for the 3rd month : '))
    global linker1 = 4.63 * 4.93
    global linker2 = 2.88 * 4.63 * 4.93
    global inpt = input('Do you want the linker value "2.88" to be computed which belongs to AICPIN BASE 2016 = 100.\n[y]es or [n]o   :')
    
    def lnkr1(m1,m2,m3,linker2,inpt):
        if inpt == 'y':
            m1 = m1 * linker2
            m2 = m2 * linker2
            m3 = m3 * linker2
            sum_of_m = m1+m2+m3
            avg_m = (sum_of_m)/3
            print(f'The DA Point for the present 3 months is {avg_m}')
        else:
            pass
    
    def lnkr2(m1,m2,m3,linker2,inpt):
        if inpt == 'y':
            m1 = m1 * linker1
            m2 = m2 * linker1
            m3 = m3 * linker1
            sum_of_m = m1+m2+m3
            avg_m = (sum_of_m)/3
            print(f'The DA Point for the present 3 months is {avg_m}')
        else:
            pass
    def preM():
        pM = input('Sir/Madam Do you have the DA Point of the Earlier 3 months or Do you have to compute it ? \n[y]es or [n]o .')
        if pM == 'y':
            bs1 = input('Do you want to include the linker 2.88 ? .[y] or [n] :: ')
            if bs1 == 'y':
                lnkr1()
            else:
                lnkr2()
            
while True: 
    try:
        calculation()

    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid Character')
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 20
    global m1 = float(input('Enter AICPIN for the 1st month : '))
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Program finished]
```

**Note:** I'm using My Android mobile for coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global` keyword is used to declare a variable that will be accessible everywhere. While declaring a variable as global, you cannot assign a value to it. You have to do that in two lines.

```
global m1
m1 = float(input('Enter AICPIN for the 1st month : '))
```

This should fix it.

> Edit

You can declare all global variable in one line:

```
global m1, m2, m3, linker1, linker2, inpt
```

Comment: @harish Please click on the ✓ mark on the left of my answer to mark as your question was answered and choose it as the answer.